# HTTP:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have 2 project:

1. rails project.
2. angularjs project.

Now I want use rails models in angularjs project. I have a `widget` model that I created by `scaffold`. Now I want add a new `widget` from angularjs project to rails project by `http` and `post` method. For this, I have below code:

`angularproject/js/app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http){
    app = this;
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/widgets.json")
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data)
            app.peaple = data;
        })
    app.addWidget = function (widget){
        $http.post("http://localhost:3000/widgets",widget)
    }
})
```

`angularproject/index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
<!--add new widget by post method in http-->
<input type="text" ng-model="app.widget.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="app.widget.price">
<input type="button" ng-click="app.addWidget(app.widget)">
<!--display all widget-->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="widget in app.peaple">
        {{widget.name}}<br/>{{widget.price}}
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I add below code to rails project:
`application_controller.rb`

```
#add this line for allow to get widget json
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers
  private
  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end
```

`widgets_controller.rb`:

```
# GET /widgets
# GET /widgets.json
  def index
    @widgets = Widget.all
  end
# POST /widgets
# POST /widgets.json
  def create
    @widget = Widget.new(widget_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @widget.save
        format.html { redirect_to @widget, notice: 'Widget was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @widget }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @widget.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

By this code, I can get `widget` json and show to user, but when I complete the field of new `widget` and post to rails controller, I get below error on console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/widgets. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63343' is therefore not allowed access.
```

and below error in rails server log:

```
Started OPTIONS "/widgets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-18 18:02:05 +0430

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/widgets"):
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (38.0ms)
```

Where is the problem? How can I add permission to `angularjs` project to add new `widget` in database?

Answer (score 1):

### Your rails should allow http "options" method(Preflighted requests). To knw more about preflighted requests check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Or check out the rack-cors gem, it allows you to configure it like a routes file

https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors